# Java's float variable doesn't show me the perfect value. the float point is weird

Tags: java, floating-point

I tried to print the float variable's value.

But the result is weird...

```
float num1 = 45.9f;
float num2 = 32.1f;

System.out.printf("%f, %f", num1, num2);

// Expected: 45.9, 32.1
// Result: 45.900002, 32.099998
```

Why does appear like that??

Sorry for the question...

Comment: Use BigDecimal, although there are drawbacks like it being slower and harder to do simple math with. if you're dealing with money go with BigDecimal, if not then float or double is good enough, just round the number.

Comment: Because there are infinitely many real numbers, and only finitely many combinations of 32 bits.  Therefore, most real numbers can't be exactly represented with a float.

Comment: Also, no need to say "sorry for the question".  Questions are what we deal with on Stack Overflow.  It's non-questions that upset us.

Comment: If you want a perfect value, use `BigDecimal`. If you want speed of execution, use the floating-point types, `float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double`. Choose one, [accuracy or speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems); you cannot have both.

Comment: If you want to print only upto 1 decimal places then you can use System.out.printf("%.1f , %.1f",num1,num2);